# Expansion of $S_n$ is less than $T_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

Let $S_n=\{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\}$ and $T_n=\{1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\}$

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n > \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n$

Now I know that I should use the binomial theorem expansion to compare each term from both sequences.

I know I will get $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\times (\frac{1}{n})^k  $
and the first few terms of the series will be $1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$

so in my mind this looks identical to $T_n$ but I am assuming there is something that occurs later in the series that will allow me to conclude that the limit of $S_n > $ limit of $T_n$

So If you could in detail show me what that 'something' is and how you conclude that I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why the self-dup?

Comment: Actually, the limits are equal: $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n$. More specific, they're both $e$. I get the thing you're trying to prove, but you're formulating it a little usuaual.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**.  In your title you said $S_n<T_n$, in the question you said $S_n>T_n$.  The former is correct, and that is what I'll prove.

By the binomial theorem,
$$\eqalign{\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^n
  &=1+\binom n1\frac1n+\binom n2\frac1{n^2}+\binom n3\frac1{n^3}+\cdots
    +\binom nn\frac1{n^n}\cr
  &=1+\frac1{1!}\frac nn+\frac1{2!}\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}
    +\frac1{3!}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3}+\cdots
    +\frac1{n!}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1}{n^n}\cr
  &<1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}\ .\cr}$$
Thus $S_n<T_n$ for all $n$.  Note however that this **does not** mean $\lim S_n<\lim T_n$, it only means $\lim S_n\le\lim T_n$.  And in fact the two limits are equal.

**Comment**.  Note that $T_n$ is a **finite** sum, it ends with $\frac1{n!}$.  From the middle of your question it looks a bit as if you think $T_n$ goes on for ever.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo Thanks for pointing out the error, it's now fixed.  The OP said $<$ in the title but $>$ in the question... very confusing :)